# Pending HTTP01 Certificate Challenge for SSL

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I'm starting with Kubernetes and I try to deploy my FastAPI service with Kubernetes. I try to use `cert-manager` to manage SSL. I created my Deployment, Service, Ingress, and ClusterIssuer. Everything seams to be working but Let's Encrypt ACME seams to not be able to reach my issuer, and the Challenge stays in "Pending" status. What am I missing?

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: myemail@xxxxxx.com # removed for StackOverflow
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-private-key
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-api
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
#      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
#  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
spec:
  rules:
    - host: api.myapp.app
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-api-service
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - api.myapp.app
      secretName: secret-ingress-cert
```

Result of the `kubectl describe challenge` command

```
Status:
  Presented:   true
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code '404', expected '200'
  State:       pending
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                     -------
  Normal  Started    19m   cert-manager-challenges  Challenge scheduled for processing
  Normal  Presented  19m   cert-manager-challenges  Presented challenge using HTTP-01 challenge mechanism
```

Result of the `kubectl get services` command:

```
NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
cm-acme-http-solver-zmcjf   NodePort       10.3.208.142   <none>         8089:30754/TCP   25m
kubernetes                  ClusterIP      10.3.0.1       <none>         443/TCP          6d2h
postgres                    NodePort       10.3.50.255    <none>         5432:30607/TCP   6d2h
my-api-service              LoadBalancer   10.3.127.2     51.91.81.209   80:32566/TCP     6d2h
```

I tried many stuff, there is my DNS: api.solfy.app which is correctly forwarding to 51.91.81.209.
It seams that maybe I only expose 80 port while ACME may look for HTTPS (port 443) challenge?

Comment: The address `10.3.127.2` is a private IP address; LetsEncrypt is never going to be able to contact a server at that address. HTTP-01 challenges will only work for services that can be reached on a public address.

Comment: W/r/t to your comments at the end of the question, from [the documentation](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/): "The HTTP-01 challenge can only be done on port 80."

Comment: My bad, I wrote `10.3.127.2` but my DNS corretly forward to the public IP "51.91.81.209" (you can check with `curl api.solfy.app`). Why LetsEncrypt is not able to reach it?

Comment: Your manifest is using the hostname `api.myapp.app`, not `api.solfy.app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seams that maybe I only expose 80 port while ACME may look for
> HTTPS (port 443) challenge?

No, your `my-api-service` is going to be exposed via nginx reverse proxy. You can see both the `80` and `443` ports are exposed in the `ingress-nginx-controller` service which has type `LoadBalancer`:

```
k get svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx
```

You should keep `my-api-service` as `ClusterIP` type, no need for another public IP separately for the service, and the service provider charges you for two public IPs.

Now, the issue is so obvious. The `HTTP-01` challenge has to happen via the `Ingress` service but, as you pointed direct service IP in your DNS records. Your DNS record should be changed from `51.91.81.209` to the `external-ip` you get from the above-mentioned command (Ingress LoadBalancer IP).

Let me know if it's not clear to you!

Comment: Ingress was not active. I added it on my cluster. Thanks!